# Meaning of "It's something all day"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The phrase is from the TV series *Mr Robot*. Mobley compares Android phone and iPhone:

> I mean, if you're talking boot times, then **it's Android all day**, and if you're talking net speed, Chrome on Android has better HTML5 compliance and runs JavaScript so much faster than Safari.

If it means "Android is way better", then I don't understand etymology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then it's Android **all day**, and  [...]

means

> then it is Android **that is the winner all day long**, and  [...]

Or

> then it is Android **that would be the winner in a series of tests that we could run during a 24 hour period**, and  [...]

Comment: Yes, I agree with this sense - from the way it's phrased I'd interpret that the relationship between boot times and android, and net speed and chrome on android are comparable, so both are meant in a positive sense  - in other words 'it's Android all day' would mean something like 'Android wins hands down'

Answer (score 1):

I think the cited example is a "non-standard" variant of the idiomatic...

> *I'd vote for Android **any day*** (if we're judging purely on the basis of boot times)
>    [*I'd bet on him any day*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bet%20on%20him%20any%20day%22)
>    [*I'd choose that any day*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22choose%20that%20any%20day%22)
>    [*I'd marry you any day*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22marry%20you%20any%20day%22)
>    *etc., etc.*

There's no particular reference to a day as being 24 hours - in the standard version it simply means *always, no matter what day of the week it is*, whereas in OP's case it would have to be interpreted as meaning *anywhen, no matter what time of day*.

Note that this usage *isn't* quite the same as the more common ***all day*** usage found in *I could eat ice-cream all day*, because that one *does* (exaggeratedly) allude to the 24-hour *duration* of a day.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that *Android all day* means (as you thought) that Android is a lot better than the Iphone with respect to boot times, meaning much faster booting. However, it could also mean that *it takes Android all day to boot*. The sentence is ambiguous, at least to me.

Comment: It is certainly not "all day to boot". Current generation of smartphones takes dozens of seconds to boot.

Comment: @NashBridges [hyperbole](http://literarydevices.net/hyperbole/)

Comment: @choster  Ah, indeed :) Wouldn't be in that case his phrase built like "if...then, *however*..." instead of "...and"? That "and" makes me think that both statements are positive